# Created a contact us form - How do I get the information sent to me via email?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I've created a contact us form. I followed this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-forms/

The tutorial is cut short though. So I've done everything, it gathers the information once a user hits the submit button.

Can anyone fill me in with the rest? How do I get the data sent my email address?

Thanks in advance, really appreciate the help! Bit annoying after getting everything else.

Comment: "How do I get the data sent to my email address" - maybe open your email client or the site of your webmail provider, then log in?

Comment: Do you want the email to be sent on the background, or are you happy for the email app to be opened, pre populated with your address and the message etc?

Comment: @barry it's not actually an email though is it? To answer your question I would like the information in the form sent in the background, without having to open another app. The thing is, if they decide to not supply an email then fair enough, i could still do with the rest of the information. I guess that would talk a server or something though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an Android developer, but the principles apply everwhere.

You need to use an SMTP client that connects to an SMTP server to send the mail.

Take a look at this Q&A for an example of how to do this: [Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: Seems like quite the project, didn't realise it was this complicated. Lots of information there though so I'll look into it, thanks!

I'm only sending information one way so no need to get their username/password for one.

Comment: The username and password are used to authenticate against Google's SMTP server. This is to help prevent spam.